# Using format() to center align and set precision which are given as inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, format

this is my problem:consider a number like 29.8245,given an amount for precision first this number should be rounded,for instance for `precision =0` it would be 30.Now this number should be center aligned in a string with a given width. for instance if `width = 10` then the final result would be:`'    30    '`
For this particular example I came up with:

```
"{:^10}".format("{0:.0f}".format(29.8245))
```

the problem is that now the numbers are hard coded and I don't know how to fix that to get the inputs into my code.I know that :

```
"{}".format()
```

is what we use in normal cases but in this problem I don't know how to combine these two codes(I don't even know is it possible or not).
Also is there a better approach  to solve the problem?

Comment: What if the user inputs a number with width greater than `width = 10` ?

Comment: @Austin well that is one of  my problems,the width could also change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly why format strings support nesting:

```
>>> width = 10
>>> precision = 0
>>> num = 29.825
>>> f'{num:^{width}.{precision}f}'
'    30    '
```

Comment: [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) are great for Python 3.6+ only code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it the will work in "old" versions of Python (before 3.6) and will continue to work in it as well:

```
res = "{:^{width}.{precis}f}".format(29.8245, precis=2, width=15)
print(repr(res))
```

As you can see, format string syntax supports nesting.

Output:

```
'     29.82     '
```

The values used for `precis` and `width` are expressions, so could involve calculations rather than being hardcoded constants as shown.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading the question wrong, but it seemed that calling format twice is exactly what OP was trying to avoid (*"I don't know how to combine these two codes"*).

Comment: @wim: Obviously I missed that part of the question—but regardless, there's not reason to call it twice and I have updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for making the point.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible solution that doesn't rely on f-strings

```
>>> '{0:^{width}.{precision}f}'.format(12.34, width=10, precision=0)
'    12    '
```